# Как можно передать в Google Analytics url страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics

Подскажите, как можно передать в Google Analytics url страницы, если код вставляется на страницу через `iframe`, внутри которого вставлен tagmanager. Других вариантов вставки кода отслеживания нет.

Размещаем статьи на внешнем сайте и пока что получаем общую статистику, но хотелось бы разбить это по статьям.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил ... передачей значения оффера, который как раз передает урл страницы с которой осуществляется переход и славо богу тагменаджер это подхватывает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать более информативные ответы. Уверен, они в будущем помогут многим вашим коллегам.